# populate expandable listview from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

This is my first time here in this site. I already did searched the web on how to populate sqlite database into expandable listview but i failed.

I follow 
[these steps](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html) on how to create an expandable listview and modify some codes to make it dynamic.

Here is my modified code. This is only to set parent text on expandable listview:

```
public void setGroupParents() {     

    String selectQuery = "select * from " + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY "+DbHelperTablon.KEY_FNAME+" ASC ";
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {        
            parentItems.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }       

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return;     
}
```

When i tried to run the emulator, the program crashed.

I am a newbie in android development and i need any help from you experts.. Thanks in advance.

Oh.. im sorry. This is the results of my LogCat... This is only the error portion..

> 03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Sample/com.Sample.MainListview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at com.Sample.MainListview.setGroupParents(MainListview.java:56)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at com.Sample.MainListview.onCreate(MainListview.java:39)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
>   03-12 07:25:10.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(367):     ... 11 more
>   03-12 07:25:12.428: ERROR/InputDispatcher(59): channel '40703be0 com.Sample/com.Sample.Drawer (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
>   03-12 07:25:12.428: ERROR/InputDispatcher(59): channel '40703be0 com.Sample/com.Sample.Drawer (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Could you post the exception?

Comment: If your app crashed show your stacktrace here from the logcat that which exception it contains

Comment: @Narkha im sorry what do you mean? im just editing the tutorial links, instead of custom parent text, i want it data from database
    public void setGroupParents() 
    {
        parentItems.add("Fruits");
        parentItems.add("Flowers");
        parentItems.add("Animals");
        parentItems.add("Birds");
    }

Comment: @PiyushGupta I was assumed there was an error in my sql statement declarations or something else thats why it crashed.  :)

Comment: i was traying to say the same that @PiyushGupta: that it would be usefull to post the stacktrace of the exception for evaluate the problem.

Comment: And another question: how may fields have the table `DbHelper.TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: @Narkha there are 8 fields. and i need to get the 2nd field and used it as parent text of the expandable listview.

Comment: are the values of `mHelper` and the returned value of `mHelper.getReadableDatabase()`distint of null?

Comment: @Narkha No, it isn't null.

Comment: which is the line of the error?

Answer (score 0):

well i guess if you initiate the database object outside your class your problem might be solved...